# FTP-server is not reachable any longer after transferring / reading a file

Tags: windows, networking, ftp, windows-server-2019

I need help with my FTP-server (based on windows server 2019).

The server seems to be configured correctly:
If I connect to the server, it's reachable, it shows me the directory and I'm also be abled to transfer data to both sides. But after transferring only one file, it seems like the server is not reachable any longer via FTP - ends with a timeout.
If I now restart the FTP-service on the server, everything works fine again, until i transferred another file, then it stucks.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the allocated FTP port range? Are you in active or passive mode?

Comment: Also, you should check your firewall/s logs, I suspect your FTP is connecting the first time ok as the port used is able to traverse the firewall.
When you go to connect a second time, the next port used is being blocked as its not in the allowable range on the firewall.

Comment: The server is running in passive mode.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to increase the range of ports, but just on the FTP-server / firewall and I will give Feedback, if this worked!